# How can I set the parameter of a class as a specific data type?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know how should I define my parameters properly and say hey this is string , that is a list or this should be tuple.
for example I have a class called Person

class Person():

```
def __init__(self,name,DOB,gender,hobbies=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.DOB = DOB
    self.gender = gender
    self.hobbies = hobbies
```

and I want to change the data types of each parameter , let's say I want name only as a string and hobbies only as a list.
And when I add an object to the class let's say person_x, and I want to give him a name it should be only a string.

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language. You can use type hints with a static type checker like mypy but the types will not be enforced at runtime. For runtime checking you can use `isinstance` or other mechanisms and maybe raise an exception for unwanted types

Comment: @TheMonarch it is still not clear for me sir , with the code I posted if I add an object and set the name parameter to lets say 5 , I will get his name as `5` but I want it to be only as a string, so when I set the name I have to say hey this should be a string and type `"5"`.

Comment: That's dynamically types languages for you! Any type is allowed and It's up to you to ensure you pass in the correct types. You can use type convserion, `self.name = str(name)` or type checks `isinstance(name, str)` for example, but you generally don't need to do that. As I mentioned, type hints plus a static type checker and a good IDE will help make sure you pass correct types while developing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir I appreciate it , now I get it.